# Burnt MOSFET in the following circuit. Why?

Tags: mosfet, failure

I made the following circuit. As the test load I used 10cm of a standard 12V LED strip to be sure I don't sink too much current.

Used 5V from uC to drive the circuit, toggling it on and off every second. It seemed to work properly but after literally a dozen of cycles M1 exploded loudly with a flame, permanently shorting its' drain and source.

What was wrong? According to datasheet, M1 can withstand over 2A of continuous current. Any ideas why it failed?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fO9nZA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

EDIT:
D1 is a red diode which turns on whenever the main load is under power (theoretically). I'd like to keep it within this circuit but can also move it away to another pin and toggle by software.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "standard 12V LED strip". There's no way to estimate how much current your LEDs are drawing based on the information giving.

Comment: Move that D1 LED so that it is in series with the drain of the 2N7002 instead of in the source path. This will bring the available ON drive to the 2N7002 up to a full 5V assuring that it fully turns on. Or dispatch the D1 LED back to the parts bag and connect the source of the FET to GND directly.

Comment: Are you actually using 12v - if so how do you provide it?

Answer (score 6):

Hypothesis: you are not fully turning on the M1 and its channel resistance remains fairly high, which cause it to overheat.
That's cause by not driving the *V<sub>GS</sub>*  of M1 low enough.
That's caused by not driving *V<sub>GS</sub>* of M2 high enough.
That's caused by presence of a diode drop of D1 at the M2 source.  D1 is an LED, so the diode drop could be, say, 1.7V.

Try the following.
Remove D1 and replace it with a short.
Remove R2 and replace it with a short.
Test the circuit.

Comment: Interesting simulation results on this one. The applied Vgs of M2 (using LTspice) is about 2.25V, which is technically high enough to make this circuit work. But the Vgs(th) of a 2N7002 ranges from 1V to 2.5V. It's possible emes is using a 2N7002 with a Vgs(th) closer to 2.5V, in which case Nick's answer is probably about right.

Comment: @DanLaks It might be a blue LED rather than a red one. Also (not related to your simulation but related to design) Vgs(th) is measured at 250uA which will give you only 118mV on the gate of M1, so more voltage is required for a good design. M1 is a tiny SOT-23 part so you have to make d*mn sure it's turned on fully and off fully if you don't want it blowing up. Finally, the gate of M1 is only rated for 12VDC absolute max. It should **not** be used at 12V. A couple blue LEDs in series could be connected between gate and source to protect the gate and D1 scrapped.

Comment: I would still bet +1 on Nick's answer being the correct one, but that gate voltage needs attention.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, exactly the point I was trying to make. The simulation has Vgs(th) around 1.5V or so, so the applied 2.25V Vgs was high enough above Vgs(th) to make the circuit work. But if the actual Vgs(th) is just a little higher (which I suspect it is) it'll be too deep in the linear region to conduct enough current. Of course of the LED is blue or white, all bets are off.